# Comparing nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime

Looking for a better way to compare a nullable date time than the following:

Any suggestions?

```
// myobject.ExpireDatetime is of DateTime?
//
if (!myobject.ExpireDateTime.IsNull() && DateTime.Compare((DateTime)myobject.ExpireDateTime, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()) < 0)
{ //error! }
```

> Edited: Sorry for confusion...myobject.ExpireDatetime is of type
>   DateTime.

Comment: In C# the word **`object`** is a keyword and it cannot be used as an identifyer (except if you write it `@object`). I think it's unclear if you have a boxed `DateTime` that may be a null reference, or if you have an unboxed "true" nullable `DateTime` (`DateTime?`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare nullable datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251902/compare-nullable-datetime-objects)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear to me, but if we have

```
DateTime? ExpireDateTime;  // could be a variable or a property
```

it's OK to say just

```
if (ExpireDateTime < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
  ...
}
```

This will be OK if `ExpireDateTime` is `null` (`HasValue` is false). Some inexperienced developers will struggle to understand [lifted operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3370150/8930), so to make it more clear, you could write

```
if (ExpireDateTime < (DateTime?)DateTime.UtcNow)
{
  ...
}
```

It's the same, but easier to read and understand.

*Never* write `.Value` if the nullable might be null, of course. You will get an `InvalidOperationException` *"Nullable object must have a value"* if you do so.

Comment: Awesome!  Yes, this is the explanation that I was really after.  That is, how to compare a nullable datetime without short circuiting logic in by checking if the value is not null...then checking the constraint on the nullable value <psuedo code> if (val.isnotnull && val.iswithinconstraint)

Comment: but,  (default(DateTime?) < DateTime.UtcNow) is false and ( default(DateTime?) > DateTime.UtcNow) is also false

Comment: @labroo Certainly. So with nullables we do not have "[trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics))", so sometimes `x < y` and `x == y` and `x > y` are all `false`.

Comment: It also depends on specific business requirements. In some occasions I might want to treat null date as "greater than" any valid date. For example: `minDate = d1 < d2 ? d1 : d2` where all three dates are nullable - in this case I want `minDate` to receive actual valid date, if any, but not null, unless both d1 and d2 are nulls.

Comment: @JustAMartin If you really want, you can write `!(ExpireDateTime >= DateTime.UtcNow)` which is the same as `ExpireDateTime < DateTime.UtcNow` if `null` is not involved, but has the opposite value when `null` is involved. However, it may be easier to read something like `!ExpireDateTime.HasValue || ExpireDateTime.Value < DateTime.UtcNow`, depending on taste.

Answer (score 41):

I would recommend you to use the following:

```
int y = Nullable.Compare<DateTime>(DateTime.UtcNow, x); 

// x is the nullable date time object.
// y will be '-1' if x is greater than DateTime.UtcNow
```

Answer (score 12):

The compiler [lifts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators/3370150) variables and generates code to check for nulls.

```
> new DateTime?()
null
> DateTime.Now > null
false
> DateTime.Now < null
false

> new int?()
null
> 10 >= null
false
> 10 =< null
false
> 10 == null
false
> 10 != null
true
```

Knowing this you can write simple code.

```
// d is a DateTime? 
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

bool after = d > now;
bool before = d < now;
bool today = d?.Date == now.Date;
```

If d is null everything will be false, else it will work like normal DateTime comparison.

Answer (score 4):

If  `ExpireDateTime` is a  `Nullable<DateTime>`i would do following instead:

```
if (ExpireDateTime.HasValue && ExpireDateTime < DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime())
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property of the nullable:

```
objet.ExpireDateTime.Value
```

---

```
if (!object.ExpireDateTime.IsNull() 
    && DateTime.Compare(objet.ExpireDateTime.Value, 
                        DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()) < 0)
{ 
}
```

Comment: There's still a smell left from the Original Question as (in the usual implementation) `System.Object` does not have a `static` member called `ExpireDateTime` (so it still won't compile).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - `ExpireDateTime` is probably an extension method.

Comment: @Oded You can't extend like that. Even with an extension method you need an identifyer or an ordinary exression before the dot (`.`). For example `(new object()).ExpireDateTime()` or `typeof(object).ExpireDateTime()` or `@object.ExpireDateTime()` all might compile with some (really crazy) extension method. But there's something wrong with just `object`. Besides, if it's a method, you can't just say `.IsNull` without first _invoking_ `ExpireDateTime`. In short, it can never ever be valid as it stands.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...object.ExpireDateTime is of type DateTime.

Comment: @JaJ It's not legal to write `object` "dot" `ExpireDateTime` in the code.