# Compare nullable datetime objects

Tags: c#, datetime, compare, nullable

I have two nullable datetime objects, I want to compare both. What is the best way to do it?

I have already tried:

```
DateTime.Compare(birthDate, hireDate);
```

This is giving an error, maybe it is expecting dates of type `System.DateTime` and I have Nullable datetimes.

I have also tried:

```
birthDate > hiredate...
```

But the results are not as expected...any suggestions?

Comment: Is null < date? What about null and null?

Comment: How are the results different from what you expected when you use `birthDate > hireDate`, because that is the easiest way to do it. C# introduced **lifted operators** to make things easy for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing nullable DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673117/comparing-nullable-datetime)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To compare two `Nullable<T>` objects use **[`Nullable.Compare<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxxt7t2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** like:

```
bool result = Nullable.Compare(birthDate, hireDate) > 0;
```

---

You can also do:

Use the Value property of the Nullable DateTime. *(Remember to check if both object Has some values)*

```
if ((birthDate.HasValue && hireDate.HasValue) 
    && DateTime.Compare(birthDate.Value, hireDate.Value) > 0)
{
}
```

If both values are Same DateTime.Compare will return you `0`

Something Like

```
DateTime? birthDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
DateTime? hireDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
if ((birthDate.HasValue && hireDate.HasValue) 
    && DateTime.Compare(birthDate.Value, hireDate.Value) > 0)
{
}
```

Comment: If nullable does not have value, you will get exception trying to access Value property

Comment: What integer values will be returned in each case, i.e. > < ==

Comment: If either of the dates is null, .Value will be null and will throw an InvalidOperationException with "Nullable object must have a value". The OP might want to add the null checks in there.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky then what do you suggest is the best method? as I do have cases where values can be null.

Comment: `var equal = Nullable<DateTime>.Compare(birthDate, hireDate);`

Comment: That long expression `(birthDate.HasValue && hireDate.HasValue) 
    && DateTime.Compare(birthDate.Value, hireDate.Value) > 0` always produces the same result as C#'s **lifted operator**, so just say `birthDate > hireDate`. Much easier when the struct overloads the `>` operator.

Comment: @Maarten `DateTime?` does not have a `Compare` method. You meant `Nullable.Compare<DateTime>(birthDate, hireDate)` instead.

Answer (score 13):

[Nullable.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/213d9ey9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Indicates whether two specified Nullable(Of T) objects are equal.

Try:

```
if(birthDate.Equals(hireDate))
```

The best way would be: [Nullable.Compare Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxxt7t2a.aspx)

```
Nullable.Compare(birthDate, hireDate));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`Nullable.Compare<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxxt7t2a.aspx) method. Like this:

```
var equal = Nullable.Compare<DateTime>(birthDate, hireDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a `null` value to be treated as `default(DateTime)` you could do something like this:

```
public class NullableDateTimeComparer : IComparer<DateTime?>
{
    public int Compare(DateTime? x, DateTime? y)
    {
        return x.GetValueOrDefault().CompareTo(y.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
var myComparer = new NullableDateTimeComparer();
myComparer.Compare(left, right);
```

Another way to do this would be to make an extension method for `Nullable` types whose values are comparable

```
public static class NullableComparableExtensions
{
    public static int CompareTo<T>(this T? left, T? right)
        where T : struct, IComparable<T>
    {
        return left.GetValueOrDefault().CompareTo(right.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
}
```

Where you'd use it like this

```
DateTime? left = null, right = DateTime.Now;
left.CompareTo(right);
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Vishal stated, simply use overriden [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6.aspx) method of `Nullable<T>`. It is implemented this way:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (!this.HasValue)    
        return (other == null);

    if (other == null)    
        return false;

    return this.value.Equals(other);
}
```

It returns `true` if either both nullable structs do not have value, or if their values are equal. So, simply use

```
birthDate.Equals(hireDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
birthDate.Equals(hireDate)
```

and do your stuff after comparison.

Or, use

```
object.equals(birthDate,hireDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the condition in the following manner

```
birthdate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue) > hireddate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic method to calculate Min or Max for any type like below:

```
public static T Max<T>(T FirstArgument, T SecondArgument) {
    if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(FirstArgument, SecondArgument) > 0)
        return FirstArgument;
    return SecondArgument;
}
```

Then use like below:

```
var result = new[]{datetime1, datetime2, datetime3}.Max();
```