# Allow null DateTime? variable comparison with DateTime variable in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

I have two variables of type DateTime and DateTime?

```
DateTime StartDateFromDb;
DateTime? StartDateFromFilter;

if(StartDateFromDb.Date == StartDateFromFilter.Date);
```

While comparing, .Date is not allowingfor StartDateFromFilter of type allow null

Thanks in advance

Comment: ``StartDateFromFilter.Value.Date``

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13673117/447156

Answer (score 3):

Use the Value property available as

```
  if(StartDateFromFilter.HasValue && StartDateFromDb.Date == StartDateFromFilter.Value.Date)
```

PS: Better to add a null value check. StartDateFromFilter must have a value.(HasValue is true when DateTime? type variable is not null)

Answer (score 2):

For any nullable type , you can use value property. 
StartDateFromFilter.Value.Date

In your case , this should work fine

```
if(StartDateFromDb.Date == StartDateFromFilter.Value.Date)
//// in this case .Date is not allowingfor StartDateFromFilter
```