# How does comparison operator works with null int?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am starting to learn nullable types and ran into following behavior.

While trying nullable int, i see comparison operator gives me unexpected result. For example, In my code below, The output i get is **"both  and 1 are equal"**. Note, it does not print "null" as well.

```
int? a = null;
int? b = 1;

if (a < b)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is bigger than {1}", b, a);
else if (a > b)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is bigger than {1}", a, b);
else
    Console.WriteLine("both {0} and {1} are equal", a, b);
```

I was hoping any non-negative integer would be greater than null, Am i missing something here?

Comment: [Here is a small .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NddZ9N) to see several cases.

Comment: @UweKeim, in the fiddle, the second overload should be `void compare(int? a, int b)`, i.e., the second parameter should be non-nullable.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) - it's down the page in the "Operators" section:

> When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one of the nullable types is `null` and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to `false` except for `!=`

So both `a > b` and `a < b` evaluate to `false` since `a` is null...

Comment: In my projects I am currently using VB.NET and it seems that `nothing <> 1` = `null` in VB whereas `null != 1` = `true` in C# - I have been using LinqPad to test the statements

Comment: I just wondered, and it's worth noting about `Lifted Operators` in C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators - I wondered if this might be the reason VB.NET returns different results

Answer (score 61):

As MSDN says

> When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one
>   of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons
>   evaluate to false except for != (not equal). It is important not to
>   assume that because a particular comparison returns false, the
>   opposite case returns true. In the following example, 10 is not
>   greater than, less than, nor equal to null. Only num1 != num2
>   evaluates to true.

```
int? num1 = 10;
int? num2 = null;
if (num1 >= num2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("num1 is greater than or equal to num2");
}
else
{
    // This clause is selected, but num1 is not less than num2.
    Console.WriteLine("num1 >= num2 returned false (but num1 < num2 also is false)");
}

if (num1 < num2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("num1 is less than num2");
}
else
{
    // The else clause is selected again, but num1 is not greater than 
    // or equal to num2.
    Console.WriteLine("num1 < num2 returned false (but num1 >= num2 also is false)");
}

if (num1 != num2)
{
    // This comparison is true, num1 and num2 are not equal.
    Console.WriteLine("Finally, num1 != num2 returns true!");
}

// Change the value of num1, so that both num1 and num2 are null.
num1 = null;
if (num1 == num2)
{
    // The equality comparison returns true when both operands are null.
    Console.WriteLine("num1 == num2 returns true when the value of each is null");
}

/* Output:
 * num1 >= num2 returned false (but num1 < num2 also is false)
 * num1 < num2 returned false (but num1 >= num2 also is false)
 * Finally, num1 != num2 returns true!
 * num1 == num2 returns true when the value of each is null
 */
```

Answer (score 45):

To summarise: any inequality comparison with null (`>=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`) returns `false` even if both operands are null. i.e.

```
null >  anyValue //false
null <= null     //false
```

Any equality or non-equality comparison with null (`==`, `!=`) works 'as expected'. i.e.

```
null == null     //true
null != null     //false
null == nonNull  //false
null != nonNull  //true
```

Comment: Is it same for both `int? nonNull` and `int notNull` ?

Comment: @КоеКто, The same behavior is for `Nullable<NumberTypes> = null`. Verified.

Answer (score 6):

Comparing C# with SQL

C#: a=null  and b=null => a==b => true

SQL: a=null and b=null => a==b => false

Answer (score 0):

If you do in your last else "else if (a == b)" you wont get any output at all. a is not greater than 1, is not less than 1 or equal to 1, is null