# Take all in ternary operator in LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio, linq-to-entities

Consider this function :

```
public List<Employees> getEmployees(....... , int? takeMax = null)
{
    // some code 
    ...

    var items = DB_Context.Employees.Where(%%%%% WHATEVER %%%%).Take(takeMax.HasValue && takeMax.Value > 0 ? takeMax.Value :  ?????? ).ToList();
}
```

How can I take all the items in case `takeMax` is NULL?

The `Take()` takes `int` , and I don't want to write something like

```
int total = DB_Context.Employees.Count();
var items = DB_Context.Employees.Where(%%%%% WHATEVER %%%%).Take(takeMax.HasValue && takeMax.Value > 0 ? takeMax.Value :  total ).ToList();
```

Any alternative ?

Comment: You might want to add braces to your condition & check. It works fine for me without any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way, where you still have to write two lines (like your example of taking count), but you do not have to calculate `Count`.

```
var query = DB_Context.Employees.Where(%%%%% WHATEVER %%%%);
var items = takeMax.HasValue && takeMax.Value > 0 ? 
                query.Take(takeMax.Value).ToList() : query.ToList();
```

Comment: You mean that the evaluation of the query would be done in the second line , right ? Nice one .

Comment: @ron Yes, until you do a `ToList()` or `foreach`, the query is not evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

You could only apply the take in that case:

```
var itemsQuery = DB_Context.Employees.Where(%%%%% WHATEVER %%%%);
if (takeMax > 0)
{
  itemsQuery  = itemsQuery.Take(takeMax);
}

var items = itemsQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Even better than mine(now deleted) `if...else` approach. Both use the same `Where`.

Comment: I might not suggest this because I might want only 10 rows out of thousands in the db. I shouldn't be retreiving all of them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Take()  is used when you do not want to retreive everything(SELECT TOP n) , so I would prefer to have filtered records at the time of fetching & not after it(getting all the records & then Take())

Comment: You don't need the `HasValue` part [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777745/how-does-comparison-operator-works-with-null-int)

Comment: @Nikita: i guess you don't have understood LINQ's deferred execution. The query is not executed in the first line but in the last line.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just tried it and it was fine. See the link that toby provided.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh, I totally missed that..thanks for pointing out !

Comment: It should be `takeMax > 0`, If you access the value property you'll an error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
public List<Employees> getEmployees(....... , int? takeMax = null)
{
// some code 


...

if(takeMax != null)
{
    return DB_Context.Employees.Where(%%%%% WHATEVER %%%%).Take(takeMax).ToList();
}
else
{
    return return DB_Context.Employees.Where(%%%%% WHATEVER %%%%).ToList();
}
```