# Why c# null can implicit convert to System.Nullable<T>, but can not a self defined Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, .net

Why `null` can implicit convert to `System.Nullable<T>` like this:

```
int? val = null;
```

but self defined `Nullable<T>` (modified from .net reference source)  cannot assign `null`, is there some compiler magic? Could anyone tell me more internal implimentation?

```
[Serializable]
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private bool hasValue;
    internal T value;

    public Nullable(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.hasValue = true;
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get
        {
            return hasValue;
        }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HasValue)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)
    {
        return HasValue ? value : defaultValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!HasValue) return other == null;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return value.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HasValue ? value.GetHashCode() : 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return HasValue ? value.ToString() : "";
    }

    public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Nullable<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

test code below, compile error

```
Nullable<int> x = null; //ERROR Cannot convert null to 'Nullable<int>' because it is a non-nullable value type
```

Comment: Because System.Nullable gets special treatment in the C# language.

Comment: @default.kramer any details?

Comment: @Asad  that 's a Nullable<T> boxing or unboxing question,  so i think its not duplicate

Comment: There are other examples of special treatment such as [lifted operators and conversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 6.1.5 of the C# 5.0 specification:

> 6.1.5 Null literal conversions
>   An implicit conversion exists from the null literal to any nullable type. This conversion produces the null value (§4.1.10) of the given nullable type.

Note that this compiler-provided implicit conversion exists only to *nullable types*. Your custom-defined `Nullable<T>` is not a nullable type as defined by the C# specification. It's just some struct that you've declared that has a lot of the features of the built-in `Nullable<T>` type (described in the referenced section 4.1.10), but which is not in fact "nullable" per the definition in C#.