# C# Is nullable int descendant of nullable decimal

Tags: c#, decimal, nullable

I have discovered by error something that surprised me.

I have this method

```
public static string PrintDecimal(decimal? input, string NumberFormat = null){ }
```

And I call this method like this

```
int? MaxFaltas = 0;
Label.Text = CustomConvert.PrintDecimal(MaxFaltas);
```

Why this is working and there are no compilation errors. I'm calling a method witch is defined to receive a `decimal?` with a `int?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just discovered something described in the spec as [lifted operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3370110/1163867).

They let you convert `Nullablt<A>` to `Nullable<B>` as long as `A` can be converted to `B`.

> **6.4.2 Lifted conversion operators**
>
> Given a user-defined conversion operator that converts from a
>   non-nullable value type `S` to a non-nullable value type `T`, a lifted
>   conversion operator exists that converts from `S?` to `T?`. This lifted
>   conversion operator performs an unwrapping from `S?` to `S` followed by
>   the user-defined conversion from `S` to `T` followed by a wrapping from `T`
>   to `T?`, except that a `null` valued `S?` converts directly to a `null` valued
>   `T?`.

Answer (score 4):

This works because int can be implicitly converted to a decimal, and therefore the nullable versions can also be implicitly converted.

```
FROM   TO
int    long , float, double, or decimal
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/27/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean.aspx