# C# Custom generic struct with same compiler behavior as Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, .net

Behold the following example with [`System.Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#.

```
int x = 5;
int? y = 3;
int? result = x + y; //no compiler warning
```

It makes sense that the compiler can figure out that `T` is an `int`, thus it can use the operator.
Also in

```
int x = 5;
int? y = 3;
bool result = x == y; //no compiler warning
```

it makes sense, if `x` was `null`, the expression would be `false`. The compiler doesn't mind.

Now I'm trying to create a lookalike `Nullable<T>` class. Let's call it `Lookable<T>`.

```
[Serializable]
public struct Lookable<T> where T : struct
{
    public Lookable(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return other != null && Value.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator Lookable<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Lookable<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Lookable<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

The idea here is straight from [.NET's source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e). In my case I'm just omitting the `HasValue` property.
Now this example would work:

```
int x = 6;
Lookable<int> y = x;
Lookable<int> z = 4;
```

The compiler can infer the types here because of the `implicit operator` correct?
What I don't understand is that this example will make the compiler unhappy:

```
int x = 5;
Lookable<int> y = 3;
var result1 = x + y; //compile error
var result2 = x == y; //compile error
```

The compiler is giving me the message:

> Operator cannot be applied to operands of type '`int`' and '`Lookable<int>`'.

Why not? And why is it possible with `Nullable<T>`? I can't find it anywhere in the source code. Would it also be possible for `Lookable<T>`?

Comment: Ok, i read wrong the example, y + 5 will work, x + y will fail...

Comment: What the heck, it works with both...

Comment: Check this gist, that's my full optional class, it mimics 100% nullable and does not cause a compiler exception: https://gist.github.com/gusmanb/fc6662d64195d4230164a7700fdaa135

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for this isn't in `Nullable<T>` - it is in the C# compiler, in particular "lifted operators" in the specification, and how they apply **specifically** to `System.Nullable<T>`. The specification references are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3370150/23354).

You cannot reproduce the `Nullable<T>` behaviour in your own types. It has special handling by both the compiler and the runtime (boxing, etc).

Comment: Mark, can you explain me why this struct works like nullable? https://gist.github.com/gusmanb/fc6662d64195d4230164a7700fdaa135 I created it myself and does not cause an exception when doing something like `Optional<int> c = 33; int fd = 33; int f = c + fd;`... now I read about lifted operators and it should cause the exception, but it compiles fine... I'm really intrigued... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gusman because there is an implicit conversion from `Optional<T>` to `T` (`public static implicit operator T(Optional<T> value)`) that can be used to find the `+` for `int`, so basically this is interpreted as `int f = (int)c + fd;`. Implicit conversion operators are explored for operators.

Comment: Ok... missed the part on the user code where he defined it as explicit. So to make the user code work he only needs to add the implicit operator, right? Thanks for the aclaration anyway.

Comment: @Gusman well... sort of; it doesn't result in the same outcomes as lifted operators do, note.  For lifted operators, `null + 5 => null`; your code would result in `5`.

Comment: Totally right Marc, that's the difference. Really, thanks a lot for the info. I use this struct every day and I was scared if it could crash because something I missed.