# comparing nullable int inside if statement does not throw

Tags: c#

Comparing a `nullable int` inside an if statement seems to work even though it's clearly a null value. The code example below demonstrates the scenario:

```
List<string> list = null;

var count = list?.Count; //null

if(count > 0) // no complaint, just evaluate to false
{
  Console.WriteLine("greater");
}

if(count == null)
{
  Console.WriteLine("wow! null < 0"); // works like charm
}
```

From the above, it seems the if statement does not throw, but rather evaluate to false. Can I trust that it will always be the case or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, you can trust that it will never throw an exception. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators

Comment: Yes, also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0464

Comment: Thanks guys. I can now safely push my code to production. :)