# Why elvis operator used in "if" statement is NOT a boolean algebra anymore?

Tags: c#

This code below:

```
class B
{
    public bool FinishedDownloading { get; set; } = false;
};

class A
{
    public B DownloadStream { get; set; }
};

A a = new A();

Console.WriteLine(a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading != false);
Console.WriteLine(a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading == true);
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
```

How on earth `a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading != false` is `true` when `DownloadStream` is `null` and `FinishedDownloading` is `false`?!

Let's forget about what happend and focus on the result.

We know this statement `a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading != false` is true, because it's not `false`, so in our universe when something is true then it should be true, beacause 1 == 1, right?

So why when we do `a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading == true` the result is now false?! Madness.

I think I kind of know what's going on here. It's because when DownloadStream is `null` then `FinishedDownloading` boolean value is not accessible, thus left side is null, so C# "thinks":

- `a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading != false`

  > Ok let's check if null value is not equal to boolean "false" value. Hmm, it certainly does not, so let's output true.
- `a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading == true`

  > Ok let's compare a null value with boolean "true" value. Hmm, that doesn't make any sense. It's not true, so let's output false.

Does anyone know if this is really the case? I find it very confusing and bug prone.

Comment: Because if `a.DownLoadStream` is null, you get `null != false`, which is true.

Comment: If a.DownloadStream == null then your expression boils down to 'if null == true' which is False

Comment: _"How on earth a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading != false is true"_ - If you write something like this `if(null != false)`, you will get - `Warning: CS0472  The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'`

Comment: @BartłomiejStyś You need to have `if(null != false)` in your code in order to see that warning, it is for testing purpose, to understand what's going on. `null` represents value of `DownloadStream` when it is `null`.

Comment: @BartłomiejStyś: use: `if (new bool?() != false){}` because that is equal to your case. You will get the warning: _"The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'"_

Comment: I guess you need something like `!a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading ?? false` when your `DownloadStream` is `null`.

Comment: Your last approach makes perfectly sense and is the best way to avoid this issue and to keep the code readable: `bool finished=a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading == true;`. What happens here is that the `==` operator will convert the `bool?` to a `bool` to make this comparison possible. This is called [lifted operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're forgetting that `Nullable<bool>` (also known as `bool?`) and `bool` are two different types with a different list of possible values.

- `bool` can either be `true` or `false`
- `bool?` can be `true`, `false` or `null`

Since you've never initialized the `DownloadStream` property, it is therefore `null`. `a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading` therefore returns a `bool?` with value `null` because `?.` **propagates the null**.

And `null != false` is true since they are two completely different values.

If you initialize the `DownloadStream` property, e.g. by doing:

```
class A
{
    public B DownloadStream { get; set; } = new B();
};
```

Then you will see that `a.DownloadStream?.FinishedDownloading != false` will return `false`, which is what you're expecting.