# Returning result of statement including the safe navigation operator as boolean

Tags: c#, safe-navigation-operator

I just started using the safe navigation operator in C# for the first time and I am wondering wether this is a correct use case for that operator:

```
public bool HasAttributes
{
    get
    {
        return this.SomeClassMember?.Attributes?.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Why exactly does this code not give me a compiler error? I thought that the result would be null if for example `this.Notification` or `this.Notification.Attributes` would be null, but `return null` on the other hand does not work as it does not seem to implicitly convert to false. If I am not using the operator correctly here, could someone explain how I use it correctly in my use case?

Comment: What happens if you write `return null > 0;` ?

Comment: @Fildor I get the warning "CS0464: Comparing with null of type 'int?' always produces 'false'". However, with the statement from my question I do not get that same warning. I guess this code more or less works by "accident" because of this behavior but it still does not seem like a proper solution to me.

Comment: Because it is a compiler warning. If you write `null`, the compiler already knows it's null. If you use `this.someMember?.Count` the compiler cannot know it will be null. The point is: `return this.SomeClassMember?.Attributes?.Count > 0;` does not result in `return null;`, it results in `return null > 0;`

Comment: This behaviour is called [lifted operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#lifted-operators) - _"Lifted operators permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types."_

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense I guess. Is it the way to go though or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: More info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3370150/43846

Comment: With a reference type you could use `??` but as that isn't available for value types the compiler is helping you out here - as otherwise you'd have to wrap the whole expression with `GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: Well, you _could_ use the [NullObject-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#C#). But I cannot possibly know if that fits in your architecture.

Comment: @Fildor Not really in my case, keeping it the way it is is probably the best idea. Thanks for the help!