# The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int32' and 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I want to build the following expression:

```
myObj.Id == null
```

`myObj.Id` is a non-nullable int. I know that if this expression is evaluated literally then the result will always be false, but I need to build this expression because an expression visitor will later examine it and do something with it.

It's perfectly possible to write this expression literally in your code, but when I try to dynamically build it with the following factory method:

```
Expression.Equal(left: /* myObj.Id */, right: /* anotherId */);
```

I get the following exception:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int32' and 'System.Object'.

This doesn't make sense since it's possible to write the very same expression literally in C#.

How can I generate that expression? `<int> == null`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators

Comment: @HansPassant I edited the question after your comment, can you look at this again? I want to build `<int> == null`. I've tried setting the `liftToNull` argument to true, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: _"This doesn't make sense since it's possible to write the very same expression literally"_ -- how? what's `anotherId` in your example? If it's not something of type `object`, how is that relevant to your need? And if it is something of type `object`, what makes you say that e.g. the expression `i == o` where `i` is `int` and `o` is object would compile? It would not. _Maybe_ what you want is to cast from the value type to a nullable type (e.g. either `Nullable<T>` or a boxed `int`) for the purposes of the expression, but without more context, it's impossible to know _what_ you need.

Comment: This feels suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @PeterDuniho You can write `1 == null` in your C# code and there wouldn't be any errors. Just that you get a warning saying this will always result to `false`. That's what I meant by what you quoted.

Comment: The phrase I quoted comes after your example attempting to explicitly build an `Expression` object. You seem to be saying that the outcome of _that_ doesn't make sense. Your comment above says something completely different. Which should I believe? In any case, the compiler has different rules than the expression API. The compiler is able to promote types and lift operators to allow `1 == null`. If you're going to build an expression explicitly, it's up to you to do all that work.

Comment: For what it's worth, when you're trying to learn how to use the expression API, it's often helpful to get the compiler to build the expression for you first. For example, compile and execute this code: `Expression<Func<int, bool>> ex = i => i == null`. Then step over in the debugger and examine the value of `ex` to see what the compiler did. Then you just do the same thing. Hint: the compiler promotes the `int` to `Nullable<int>` aka `int?`

Comment: @PeterDuniho "The compiler is able to promote types and lift operators to allow 1 == null." Isn't the purpose of the third argument of the `Expression.Equal` method exactly the same thing? It's a boolean called "liftToNull" shouldn't passing `true` for that argument mimic the behavior of the compiler in this case?!

Comment: First of all, I have no idea what you mean by _"third argument of the `Expression.Equal` method"_. Your post passes only two arguments. Second, whatever you think, obviously the answer is "no", because it doesn't work. It's up to you to add the necessary logic to make compatible operands for the operator.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "I have no idea what you mean by third argument of the Expression.Equal method" after saying that I then mentioned that it's a boolean named liftToNull :/

Comment: That parameter exists in an overload completely different from the one you claim to be calling. If you want to ask questions about the overload that includes that parameter, you need to show the code that calls that overload. That said, the other overload (the one you didn't even call) does not use the parameter in the way you seem to think. You want to return `false`, but lifting the operator as nullable would result in a return value of `null`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ok. Thank you for your help. Maybe be a little less harsh next time, my friend ;) Especially to the people less experienced than me for example, they get discouraged easily. Anyway, your advice "...when you're trying to learn how to use the expression API, it's often helpful..." helped me. Right, it's converting the left side in this case to a nullable int type, as you said. So, thank you, again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I generate that expression?  == null?

The compiler promotes the `int` to a nullable type, i.e. `Nullable<int>`, also known as `int?`. You would need to do the same.

As a general technique, it is often helpful to use the compiler itself to show you how to build an `Expression` object that does what you want. For example, to answer your specific question, how to generate that expression, just write the expression you want, compile it, and run it in the debugger so you can look to see what the compiler did:

```cs
Expression<Func<int, bool>> ex = i => i == null;
```

If you do that, you will find an expression that has a `Body` value of `"(Convert(i) == null)"`. That is, the node type is `Equal`, the right operand is `null`, and the left operand is a `Convert` node, the operand of which is the `int` value `i`, and the destination type of which is `Nullable<int>`.

With that information in hand, it should be relatively easy now to write the C# code that will actually build that expression. Of course, an alternative is to just use the declaration above (or something similar) and *always* let the compiler build the `Expression` object for you. I personally prefer to not write `Expression`-building code if I can help it. It's very verbose and error-prone, so any time the compiler can do the work for me (which is very often), I let it.