# C#: How is string interpolation possible with null literals

Tags: c#

Could someone please explain how string interpolation is possible with null literals, like in the following example.

`var output = "Hello" + null + " World"'` => "Hello World"

My suspicion would be [Operate Lifting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators), which appears to take `default(string)` whilst interpolating. Or a potential implicit conversion from `Nullable<string>` to `string` that returns `default(string)` in the case the input string is null.

Any assistance in helping my understanding would be much appreciated.

Comment: ...there is no C# string interpolation in your post: you are confusing concatenation with interpolation, and concatenation is not interpolation, and C#'s `String`'s `+` operator allows concatenation with `null` because it results in better _programmer ergonomics_

Comment: The "lifted operator" concept only applies to value-types in C#/.NET (i.e. `struct` types and primitive values) that are contained within a `System.Nullable<T>`, this does not apply to reference-types, including `String`, and [the C# language has a special-case rule that explicitly says that during concatenation `null` will be treated the same as `String.Empty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#string-concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please explain how string interpolation is possible with null literals, like in the following example.
>
> ```cs
> var output = "Hello" + null + " World";
> Console.WriteLine( output ); // "Hello World"
> ```

- Your post contains an example of **string concatenation** using the `+` operator.
- Your post does not demonstrate string interpolation, which is a separate language feature that requires the use of `$`-prefixed string literals and `{}` placeholders, which can be compiled with very different semantics depending on the use-case (including trivial concatenation, or a `FormattableString` instance, and other weird things too, [especially since C# 10 in 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/string-interpolation-in-c-10-and-net-6/)).
- However, in both cases (string concatenation, and string interpolation), if any of the operands or arguments (respectively) are `null` then they are treated the same as a zero-length (empty) `String` (i.e. `String.Empty`).

  - This behaviour is specifically documented [in the C# language guide's page on the `+` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#string-concatenation) (emphasis mine):

    > #### String concatenation
    >
    > When one or both operands are of type string, the `+` operator concatenates the string representations of its operands (**the string representation of `null` is an empty string**):
  - The behaviour is the same for other features of .NET and the BCL that involve concatenating, and interpolating, `null` references into, or with, `String` values, [such as the static method `String.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-7.0#system-string-concat(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))):

    > An Empty string is used in place of any `null` element in values.

---

> My suspicion would be Operate Lifting, which appears to take default(string) whilst interpolating. Or a potential implicit conversion from Nullable to string that returns default(string) in the case the input string is null.

- Your thoughts are incorrect, sorry: C# 8.0's nullable-reference-types feature is unrelated to the C# 2.0 *nullable-types* feature, despite sharing the same shorthand syntax: so a `String?` declaration **does not** mean `Nullable<String>`.

  - `Nullable<T>` is used to represent nullable-value-types, and it cannot be used with reference-types like `String`. **If you ever try to use `Nullable<String>` then you will get a compile-time error because `T` in `Nullable<T>` is constrained to value-types only**.
  - Similarly, the *operator lifting* concept only applies to cases involving `Nullable<T>`. When reference-types (and so, `null`) is involved then the behaviour is entirely defined by the operator's implementation...

    - ...in most case this is a `public static TResult operator+( TOperand1 left, TOperand2 right )` method.
    - However, `String` is an exception to this rule: there is no `operator+` method defined on the `String` type and instead the compiler handles it itself, this is necessary because string literals can be concatenated at compile-time by the compiler itself.
    - Another exception is if the `operator+( T left, String right )` *on a different type* is invoked, and in that case the `String right` operand *might* very-well be `null`, and dealing with that correctly is another problem and I don't want to get too sidetracked here.